# Unexpected iterator behaviour when using peekable

Tags: rust

```
use std::str::Chars;

trait Extractor {
    fn peek_first(&mut self) -> Option<char>;
}

impl <'a> Extractor for Chars<'a> {
    fn peek_first(&mut self) -> Option<char> {
        let mut pk = self.peekable();
        pk.peek().and_then(|c| Some(*c))
    }
}

#[cfg(test)]
mod tests {
    use std::str::Chars;
    use super::Extractor;

    #[test]
    fn peek_first_test() {
        let mut iterator: Chars;
        iterator = "".chars();
        assert_eq!(iterator.peek_first(), None);
        assert_eq!(iterator.as_str(), "".to_string());

        iterator = "A".chars();
        assert_eq!(iterator.peek_first(), Some('A'));
        assert_eq!(iterator.as_str(), "A".to_string());

        iterator = "AB".chars();
        assert_eq!(iterator.peek_first(), Some('A'));
        assert_eq!(iterator.as_str(), "AB".to_string());
    }
}
```

I am trying out traits and wanted to put a peek_first() on an Chars iterator. As you can see I use a peekable to get a peekable iterator off the self iterator. I made a test to see if the peek_first() would not alter the self iterator state but it did. The peeked for element changes the underlying iterator and advances it.

The test

```
assert_eq!(iterator.as_str(), "A".to_string());
```

fails as iterator.as_str() evaluates to an empty string.

Is this correct behaviour or not? I couldn't find this in any of the documentation for rust.

Comment: Why do you try to recode peek ? why not just use it ? https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2015&gist=14b210184e2d30df299a3caaf2b1cebd

Comment: I wanted to hide the creation of a peekable to make it more generic

Comment: I recommend stating your actual goal in your question, not just what you tried and how it failed.  This way the answers you get will be a lot more useful.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The documentation of [`Iterator::peekable()`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#method.peekable) explicitly documents this behaviour:

> Note that the underlying iterator is still advanced when `peek` is called for the first time: In order to retrieve the next element, `next` is called on the underlying iterator, hence any side effects (i.e. anything other than fetching the next value) of the `next` method will occur.

Since `Peekable` works on arbitrary iterators, it can only use the standard iterator interface to peek at the next element, and the only way to get the next element from a generic `Iterator` is to call `next` on it.

I'd like to add a bit more context on what's going on in your code.  The struct `Peekable` is an iterator adapter.  If you have an iterator `iter`, you can call `iter.peekable()` to get a *new* iterator that supports peeking at the next element.  The method `peekable()` takes `self` by value, which means it consumes the original iterator.  So the standard way to use it is code like this:

```
let mut iter = "abc".chars().peekable();
```

Now `iter` is a peekable iterator, and peeking does *not* advance `iter` itself, but only the underlying iterator, which is wrapped in `Peekable` and not directly accessible anymore.

In your code, however, you create a new `Peekable` wrapper everytime `peek_first()` is called.  The wrapper is dropped at the end of `peek_first()`.  In your test function you only see the underlying iterator, which is advanced every time, as stated in the documentation.

So why is it even possible to retain access to the underlying iterator if `peekable()` takes `self` by value and consumes it?  This is because of [the forwarding implementation of the `Iterator` trait for mutable references to iterators](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/std/iter/trait.Iterator.html#impl-Iterator-13):

```
impl<'_, I> Iterator for &'_ mut I
where
    I: Iterator + ?Sized;
```

The `peek_first()` method receives `self` by mutable reference, so it can't consume the underlying iterator.  It instead uses the forwarding implementation for mutable references to iterators, and only consumes the mutable reference.

As a side note, you use `.and_then(|c| Some(*c))` to turn an `Option<&T>` into an `Option<T>`.  There is a dedicated method for this, which is called `cloned()`.

Comment: Thanks. I was put on the wrong track by peek() itself. I now understand that the peekable is not advanced but Iterator is. It means my tests are incorrect and not the implementation.

Comment: I will be using cloned() from now on. Thank you.