# futures_util::stream::Peekable not peeking

Tags: asynchronous, rust, websocket, rust-tokio

Being familiar with `peekable()` and `Peek` from `Iterator` I thought I knew how the `futures` version would behave.

But to my surprise it's not peeking - it's actually taking items off the Stream such that they're not available when I call `next()`.

When I await `peek_first_message()` in the code below multiple times it display *different* websocket messages.

```rust
#[derive(Debug, Deserialize)]
struct WsMessage {
   ... // elided
}

async fn peek_first_message(
    mut read: Pin<&mut impl Stream<Item = Result<Message, Error>>>,
) -> anyhow::Result<()> {
    let read = read.peekable();
    tokio::pin!(read);
    let x = read
        .as_mut()
        .peek()
        .await
        .ok_or(anyhow::anyhow!("websocket closed before first message"))?
        .as_ref();
    let ws: WsMessage = match x {
        Ok(v) => { serde_json::from_slice(v.to_text()?.as_bytes())? },
        Err(e) => { return Err(anyhow::anyhow!("fail")) },
    };
    println!("{ws:?}");
    return Ok(())
}

#[tokio::main]
async fn main() {
    let url = url::Url::parse("wss://127.0.0.1:12345").unwrap();
    let (ws_stream, _) = tokio_tungstenite::connect_async(url).await.expect("Failed to connect");
    let (_, read) = ws_stream.split();
    tokio::pin!(read);

    peek_first_message(read.as_mut()).await;
    peek_first_message(read.as_mut()).await;
    peek_first_message(read.as_mut()).await;
}
```

I only `peek` in `peek_first_message` and yet when I inspect the print statements I see that the peeked message is not printed out by the `process_messages` function. This is as if I just called `next()` in the peeking function. What's going on here?

Comment: I'm so confused - the docs at the definition say `iter::Peakable::peak` doesn't advance the iterator. Why would `peek` call `next`? I thought the reason it existed was so we could not advance it?

Comment: It does not advance the `iter::Peekable`, it does advance the underlying iterator, it has to, to get a value. Where do you suppose it gets a value from if not from `next()`?

Comment: Ah I see why I was confused now. Yep, `Peekable` is of course a new iterator. Going back to the original iterator would obviously see one item advanced. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That's exactly the expected behaviour, since you create a new `Peekable` in the function it has to fill it's buffer by calling `next` of the underlying iterator every time. `Peekable` on iterators [calls `next` too if its buffer is empty](https://doc.rust-lang.org/src/core/iter/adapters/peekable.rs.html#216).

If you want to keep the buffer you have to pass the `Peekable` around, since it contains the buffer, not the underlying reader.

[Sven Marnach](https://stackoverflow.com/users/279627/sven-marnach) provides an excellent [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52872890/442760) for a similar problem with regular `Iterator`s and `Peekable`